# How to crop images based on mask threshold?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I have to crop a lot of images manually. Not the funniest thing to do. So I thought I'd try to do it using Python.

I can detect the subject, create a mask, but I have no idea how to get the points from the very bottom part and crop based on them.

Any help is appreciated

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image5.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 192, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cv2.imwrite('result5.png', thr)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `cv.boundingRect`

Comment: Not sure how you can tag with `OpenCV` and `ImageMagick`, but you can do it with the latter like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770591/2836621

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean to crop around the subject or only the part below the subject?

Comment: i can crop the top part by finding the human pose estimation like eyes, nose, nose bridge. that part is fine. I just need to crop the bottom part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to find all external contours using cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL and pick the bottom most point, like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

im = cv2.imread('images/tennis.jpg')

# Percent of original size
scale_percent = 20 
width = int(im.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(im.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# Resize image
im = cv2.resize(im, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Canny
canny_output = cv2.Canny(im, 120, 240)

# Find external contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny_output, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cv2.drawContours(im, [contours[0]], 0, (0,255,0), 3) # Uncomment this line to see what contour opencv is finding

# Pick the bottom most point and add an offset (whatever value you want, this is just for aesthetics)
c = contours[0]
bottommost = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])[1] + 5

# Crop image
im = im[:bottommost, :]

# Show image
cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Very clever ! I just want to understand how it works. Why are you scaling the image to 20 % ? and what are the canny output values does ? those 120,240 ?

Comment: Also, there's situations where the very bottom point is a just a small dot...like a pixel...than it's not very accurate :( something about that nonzero that other people suggested :( but it's getting close to what I'd need.

Comment: Hi @Andie31, the scaling doesn't do anything I've added it so I could see the entire image on my screen, you can change that variable to back to 100.

Comment: when you pass cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL as an argument to findContours, opencv will return a list of the external contours of your image where the first contour (index 0) is the outermost one. so if you perform np.amax on that array you should be able to find a good cropping point.

Comment: Hey Felipe. Thank you for helping me with this. I still have a problem when there's some noise in the picture below the shoe...like small dirt in the picture...is there a way to remove that ? It's getting very close to what I need. This is one example...https://imgur.com/dgbCtpV

Comment: @Andie31 try to blur the image before using canny detection: `code` blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0) and them make sure you reference the blurred image on your canny detection line

Comment: sweet ! that was fast ! one last question, is there are way to get the topmost points ? thanks you !

Comment: yes, replace this bottommost = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])[1] by this topmost = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])[1]       good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Very good thinking I'd say! now the implementation:

```
xx,yy = thrs.nonzero()
max_crop_h = xx.max()
crop = img[:max_crop_h,:]
```

numpy has your back!

Comment: If only I could implement this  :) I already got this suggestion on the chat yesterday with the nonzero() but i have no clue how to implement it. I'm a photographer, my programming skills are limited.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I tried that imagemagick  but it's not what I need :(